# need help on limit question

Tags: real-analysis

need to find limit of $f(x)=((x^2-x-6)^2)/(x+2)^2$ as $x$ tends to $-2$.
so $f(x)$ can be cancelled down to $(x-3)^2$.

I need to be really formal when taking the limit of $(x-3)^2$. this is what I did:

$$\lim_\limits{x\to-2} f(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to-2} (x-3)^2=\left(\lim_\limits{x\to-2} x-3\right)^2$$

Now since we know the polynomial function $x-3$ is continuous and in particular continuous at $x=-2$, by the algebra of continuous functions, we have:
$$\left(\lim_\limits{x\to-2} x-3 \right)^2=((-2)-3))^2=(-5)^2=25.$$

Is this OK?

Comment: It has to many detail and it is not really nice formulated, but ok, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

By noting that $x^2-x-6=(x-3)(x+2)$, the function 
$$
f(x)=\frac{(x^2-x-6)^2}{(x+2)^2}
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
f(x)=\left(\frac{(x-3)(x+2)}{x+2}\right)^{\!2}=(x-3)^2
$$
in its whole domain (that is, for $x\ne-2$). Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to-2}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-2}(x-3)^2=25
$$
because $g(x)=(x-3)^2$ is everywhere continuous.

Answer (score 0):

it is $\lim_{ x \to -2}\frac{(x+2)^2(x-3)^2}{(x+2)^2}=\lim_{x \to -2}(x-3)^2=25$
because $f(x)=(x-3)^2$ is a continous function

Comment: my lecturer is very fussy and she says, why can we plug in -2?